# How to drag layers on two stages with KineticJS?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have layers on two separate stages. When one gets dragged, I want the other to move to the same position. However, once one is dragged, the other becomes undraggable. Is this a bug or is there a better way to do it?

```
layer1.on('dragmove', function() {
    layer2.setPosition(layer1.getPosition());
    layer2.draw();
});

layer2.on('dragmove', function() {
    layer1.setPosition(layer2.getPosition());
    layer1.draw();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aWsuJ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like we have to draw the other layer on drag end--not sure why.

```
layer1.on('dragmove', function() {
    layer2.setPosition(layer1.getPosition());
    layer2.draw();
});

layer1.on('dragend', function() {
    layer2.draw();
});

layer2.on('dragmove', function() {
    layer1.setPosition(layer2.getPosition());
    layer1.draw();
});

layer2.on('dragend', function() {
    layer1.draw();
});
```

Comment: An odd find indeed. You should raise this issue on the github page.